# Difference between MultiheadAttention and Attention layer in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, translation, attention-model

What is the difference between the following layers in Tensorflow: `tf.keras.layers.Attention`, `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` and `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention`?

Also how to implement `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` using fundamental layers like Dense, Add, LayerNormalization, etc? I want to understand the exact operations happening inside [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention#the_attention_layer) tutorial.

Comment: BTW, although Stackoverflow community doesn't like these questions but I think it's a good and valid question for clarification of what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://paperswithcode.com/ is a good resource to understand nuance of different deep learning terminologies and implementation

The general definition of attention mechanism in the transformer model:

> **Attention Mechanisms** are a component used in neural networks to model long-range interaction, for example across a text in NLP. The key idea is to **build shortcuts between a context vector and the input, to allow a model to attend to different parts**. - paperswithcode

[image]

*In my own words*, the "shortcuts" attention is created by doing sequential matrix multiplications of the  "**query**" (inputs) to "**value**" (the target that you want to map the inputs to), and between there, there is a "**key**" that acts like a signal that the query theoretically should make use of to project the query to the value. And the commonnoutput of the attention mechanism is a vector/matrix/tensor representation of that encodes this shortcut.

There are many variants on these "shortcuts" (aka attention mechanisms) that researchers have tried to find the optimal connection from query + key -> value. See list on https://paperswithcode.com/methods/category/attention-mechanisms-1

### Attention vs MultiHeadAttention

[image]

*In my own words*, the main differentiator between general Attention and MultiHeadAttention is the redundancy put into "MultiHead" inputs. If single head (general) attention maps one Q + K to V, **think of multi-head as creating multiple Qs that corresponds to multiple Ks and you want to create the shortcut to multiple corresponding Vs**.

In code, assuming that the initialization for `Attention`, `MultiHeadAttention` are the same, the `output_tensor` values for the following should be the same:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention, MultiHeadAttention


layer = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=1, key_dim=2)
target = tf.keras.Input(shape=[8, 16])
source = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4, 16])
output_tensor, weights = layer(target, source,
                               return_attention_scores=True)




layer_vanilla = Attention()
target_vanilla = tf.keras.Input(shape=[8, 16])
source_vanilla = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4, 16])
output_tensor_vanilla, weights_vanilla = layer_vanilla([target_vanilla, source_vanilla],
                               return_attention_scores=True)

print(output_tensor)
print(output_tensor_vanilla)
```

[out]:

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 16), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='multi_head_attention_6/attention_output/add:0', description="created by layer 'multi_head_attention_6'")

KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 16), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='attention_3/MatMul_1:0', description="created by layer 'attention_3'")
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention

### Attention vs AdditiveAttention

Additive Attention is an interesting one; it is the OG attention mechanism:

> Additive Attention, also known as Bahdanau Attention, uses a one-hidden layer feed-forward network to calculate the attention alignment score

Details: https://paperswithcode.com/method/additive-attention

Before "IMOW", lets look at the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AdditiveAttention

layer_bdn = AdditiveAttention()
target_bdn = tf.keras.Input(shape=[8, 16])
source_bdn = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4, 16])
output_tensor_bdn, weights_bdn = layer_bdn([target_bdn, source_bdn],
                               return_attention_scores=True)

print(output_tensor_bdn)
```

[out]:

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 8, 16) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'additive_attention')>
```

Comparing the implementations:

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/layers/attention/attention.py#L30-L204
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/layers/attention/additive_attention.py#L30-L178

https://www.diffchecker.com/5i9Viqm9/

[image]

The general `Attention` has:

```
scores = self.concat_score_weight * tf.reduce_sum(
                    tf.tanh(self.scale * (q_reshaped + k_reshaped)), axis=-1
                )
```

where the initializer can be set to `initializer="ones"` if `if self.score_mode == "concat"`:

```
        if self.score_mode == "concat":
            self.concat_score_weight = self.add_weight(
                name="concat_score_weight",
                shape=(),
                initializer="ones",
                dtype=self.dtype,
                trainable=True,
            )
```

but the `AdditiveAttention` uses the glorot initializer if the  `self.use_scale` is set to `True`:

```
        if self.use_scale:
            self.scale = self.add_weight(
                name="scale",
                shape=[dim],
                initializer="glorot_uniform",
                dtype=self.dtype,
                trainable=True,
            )
```

There are further nuances in the implementation though.

*In my own words,* additive attention is the earlier definition of the general attention mechanism. They achieve the same purpose of single headed attention. And if the initializations and scaling are set equally, additive attention == general attention.

### Q: Then what should I be using when choosing the attention layer?

A: Depends on what is the ultimate goal, if the goal is replicate the original Bahdanau paper, then additive attention would be the closest. If not, then the vanilla attention is most probably what you want.

### Q: What about multi-head?

A: In most cases, you will **always use multi-head attention** since

- Additive attention is a type of vanilla attention with specified initialization and operations
- Attention is a type of multi-head attention where no. of heads is set to 1

Comment: I think I'll have to upvote and consider your answer as the winner just based on the content that you provided (kidding). But genuinely thanks a lot for such a great clarification.